# Using Task.FromResult v/s await in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I am new to C# async programming and need to see if which of the following is a preferred way to deal with Task object.

I have a class that does this:

```
var value = this.SomeFunction(...);

var innerValue = await Task.FromResult(value.Result);
```

`Somefunction` looks like below.

```
protected async Task<JObject> Somefunction(..)
{
 ..
 returns JBoject
 ..
}
```

This works fine as expected. Now, I have a suggestion that I shouldn't be using `Task.FromResult` with `async` functions.
Instead, I should be using something like:

```
var innerValue = await value; //..this works fine too
```

**But I am not really sure why the 1st one isn't a good practice to get the same thing done**. 
Any leads would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: What do you expect from Task.FromResult( value.Result )? Getiing the Result from the value task (which is bad because of the implicit Wait) and wrapping that value with a task, just to await that to get the result

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Let's go through what you're doing and say precisely why it is wrong.

```
var value = this.SomeFunction(...);
```

First off: use `var` when the type is either clear or unimportant.  **The type is not clear here and it is important**.

Second: Name functions that are asynchronous with an `Async` suffix.

Let's fix up your example. It's still wrong, but now it is more clear:

```
Task<Toast> toastTask = this.StartToasterAsync();
Toast toast = await Task.FromResult(toastTask.Result);
```

**This workflow is completely wrong.**  Let's translate it into English.  Here's my to-do list for today:

- Put some bread in the toaster.
- While the bread is toasting I could be doing other work, but instead, **stare at the toaster doing nothing else until it is done**.
- Get the toast from the toaster, and start a new to-do list.
- The new to-do list is: *Obtain the piece of toast that I am now holding.*
- Execute that to-do list.  While I'm waiting for the to-do list to complete, go do other work, **but the to-do list is always already complete because the job is to obtain a result that I have already obtained**.  So don't do other work. Just check that yes, I am in fact holding the piece of toast I just wrote a to-do list about.
- Now I have a piece of toast.

This workflow is an insane way to make toast. It works -- you end up with a piece of toast at the end -- but no sensible person would do this, and you should not write the equivalent computer program:

- It is an "asynchronous" workflow where **every possible asynchronous advantage has been removed**.
- The first step -- waiting for the toaster to pop -- has been synchronously waited.
- The second step -- asynchronously wait for a task that has already completed -- is never asynchronous!

Never never never write asynchronous code this way.

The right workflow for making a piece of toast is:

- Put the bread in the toaster and start it toasting.
- Do other work until the toast pops.
- Fetch the toast.

And as we'd expect, the correct way to write your program is much simpler:

```
Task<Toast> toastTask = this.StartToasterAsync(...);
Toast toast = await toastTask;
```

Or even better:

```
Toast toast = await this.StartToasterAsync(...);
```

You're new to this and you have not internalized the meanings of the various operations on asynchronous workflows.  The operations in your little program are:

- `.Result` means *stop being asynchronous and do nothing until the result is available*.  Note that **this can cause deadlocks**.  You are stopping a thread until the result is available; **what if you are stopping the thread that was going to produce the result in the future**?  Imagine for instance that we did a to-do list of "(1) Order a box of chocolates from the internet. (2) Do nothing until the chocolates arrive. (3) Get the chocolates out of the mailbox."  That workflow does not complete because there is a synchronous wait for a result that requires you to do work *in the future*.
- `await` means *this workflow cannot continue until the result is available so asynchronously wait for it*.  Go off and find other work to do, and when the result is available, we'll start again here.

Note that both of them mean the same thing, in that *both are points in a workflow where the workflow does not proceed until the result is available*. But they are *completely different* in that `Result` is a *synchronous* wait, and `await` is an *asynchronous* wait.  **Make sure you understand this**.  It is the most fundamental point that you must understand.

And finally

- `FromResult` means *someone needs a task, but I already have the result of that task, so make a task that is already complete*.  When it is `await`ed or when `Result` is called on it, either way, it returns the result immediately.

It is unusual to call `FromResult`. If you are in an asynchronous workflow, normally you would just `return result;` to signal that a task was complete.

Comment: Pretty much the only time I use `FromResult` is when I have a hierarchy with a virtual async method where one of the implementations doesn't actually need to do any async work, and so I prefer returning a completed task rather than having an `async`-marked method with no `await`s.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in the first version is not the use of `Task.FromResult`, which, from the documentation:

> Creates a `Task<TResult>` that's completed successfully with the specified result

The problem is the call `value.Result` which performs a synchronous wait. So, you are essentially asynchronously waiting for a synchronous result.

Notice that the first version is a bad wrapper (because of the code that must be generated for the `await` call) around this:

```
var value = this.SomeFunction(...);
var innerValue = value.Result;
```

To sum up, just use this:

```
var innerValue = await value;
```

Or, if there's no code to run between `value` and `innerValue`, you can ignore the assignment of `value` altogether

```
var innerValue = await this.SomeFunction(...);
```

Comment: The best option is var innerValue = await this.SomeFunction(...) and in most cases an .ConfigureAwait(False)

Comment: @SirRufo We don't really know if the OP does not want to run other code between starting `SomeFunction` and needing the result, but I added that as an option

Comment: We can only talk about the code we see. Maybe the OP does want to run a total different code - should we talk about that too ;o)